# ejabberd pubsub unsubscribe issue

Tags: xmpp, publish-subscribe, ejabberd

I have issues when I try to unsubscribe from a pubsub node.

I am writting a BOSH client in js.

This is how I subscribe (with a full JID) :

```
<body rid='1023502710' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='2ded0255fc6e8bf912a2871d415173faadecfea6'>
<presence xmlns='jabber:client'/>
<presence from='sav1@my.server.com/my_resource' to='amd.my.server.com/sav' xmlns='jabber:client'/>
<iq to='pubsub.my.server.com' type='set' xmlns='jabber:client' id='5007:sendIQ'>
    <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
        <subscribe node='/home/monitoring/sav' jid='sav1@my.server.com/my_resource'/>
    </pubsub>
</iq>
</body>
```

On my next bind request, I receive the following stanza (because I've subscribe with a node attribute) :

http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html#example-24 : An entity MAY also request all of its subscriptions at a specific node (e.g., if it has subscriptions with multiple SubIDs) by including a 'node' attribute on the  element.

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'>
<message xmlns='jabber:client' from='pubsub.my.server.com' to='sav1@my.server.com/my_resource'>
    <event xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event'>
        <items node='/home/monitoring/sav'>
            <item id='monitor'>
                <!-- some pubsub information -->
            </item>
        </items>
    </event>
    <delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='amd.my.server.com' stamp='2012-09-14T12:36:28Z'/>
</message>
<iq xmlns='jabber:client' from='pubsub.my.server.com' to='sav1@my.server.com/my_resource' id='5007:sendIQ' type='result'>
    <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
        <subscription jid='sav1@my.server.com/my_resource' subscription='subscribed' subid='543990DD8E6E6' node='/home/monitoring/sav'/>
    </pubsub>
</iq>
<message xmlns='jabber:client' from='pubsub.my.server.com' to='sav1@my.server.com/my_resource' type='headline'>
    <event xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event'>
        <items node='/home/monitoring/sav'>
            <item id='monitor'>
                <!-- some pubsub information -->
            </item>
        </items>
    </event>
    <headers xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/shim'>
        <header name='Collection'>/home/monitoring/sav</header>
        <header name='SubID'>5435B7F0CA392</header>
        <!-- a lot of other SubIDs -->
    </headers>
</message>
</body>
```

In the headers section, I receive a lot of SubID. I suppose the reason for this is bad unsubscribe.

When I end my session, I unsubsribe from every SubID :

```
<body rid='1023502724' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='2ded0255fc6e8bf912a2871d415173faadecfea6'>
<iq to='pubsub.my.server.com' type='set' xmlns='jabber:client' id='5008:sendIQ'>
    <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
        <unsubscribe node='/home/monitoring/sav' jid='sav1@my.server.com' subid='5435B7F0CA392'/>
    </pubsub>
</iq>
<!-- a lot of other unsubscribed iqs -->
</body>
```

The answer is immediate :

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'>
<iq xmlns='jabber:client' from='pubsub.my.server.com' to='sav1@my.server.com/my_resource' type='error' id='5008:sendIQ'>
    <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
        <unsubscribe node='/home/monitoring/sav' jid='sav1@my.server.com' subid='5435B7F0CA392'/>
    </pubsub>
    <error code='401' type='cancel'>
        <unexpected-request xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
        <not-subscribed xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#errors'/>
    </error>
</iq>
</body>
```

No other SubID is mentionned except the first I initially received.

What am I doing wrong ?

I am running ejabberd 2.1.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the resource should be passed with the jid on a subscribe. I don't know if that is just something left in the example, but that may be messing things up.

Comment: That's what I use to do, so I made it in order to fix another problem (I don't remember what it was : I'll ask my team about, but I think it was when peaple didn't unsubscribe properly, for any reason, eg browser crash or brutal shutdown). I will try this again, but I don't know what information is kept in ejabberd. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try doing an unsubscribe with the full JID that is associated with the subscription instead of the base JID you are currently using.

You can get the JID from your response to your request for current subsriptions.  The jid attribute contains the full jid the subscription is associated with.

```
<iq xmlns='jabber:client' from='pubsub.my.server.com' to='sav1@my.server.com/my_resource' id='5007:sendIQ' type='result'>
    <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
        <subscription jid='sav1@my.server.com/my_resource' subscription='subscribed' subid='543990DD8E6E6' node='/home/monitoring/sav'/>
    </pubsub>
</iq>
```

Comment: I don't know full JID, but I should try this. Thanks

Comment: It is in the response to your get subscriptions request.  See my update.

Comment: Well, I don't know previouses full JID kept by ejabberd after dirty logoffs. Now, I always use the same resource, so I always have the same full jid. As you can see in my question, ejabberd returns only one subscription response, but THEN tells me about all others subids associated with my bare jid.